# Get the recent record from a query that have multiple of the same records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to query from some tables that have duplicate records with the same unique id but I just want the recent record with that unique id

```
select tblEmpl.*, tblFtpTrans.actiondate, tblFtpTrans.actionflag, tblLocs.descript
from tblEmpl 
left join tblFtpTrans on tblEmpl.eight_id = tblFtpTrans.eight_id 
join TblLocs on tblLocs.location = tblEmpl.location
where (tblFtpTrans.ActionFlag='N' or tblFtpTrans.ActionFlag = 'D')
and tblEmpl.estatus='A' and tblEmpl.location='TRN'
order by ActionDate desc;
```

| Unique Id | fname | lname | actiondate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9442 | Tom | lee | 2020-12-19 |
| 9442 | Tom | lee | 2020-10-29 |
| 3969 | Pat | Ross | 2015-05-21 |
| 2572 | Amy | lee | 2014-11-24 |
| 2572 | Amy | lee | 2016-04-07 |

What I would want is

| Unique Id | fname | lname | actiondate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9442 | Tom | lee | 2020-12-19 |
| 2572 | Amy | lee | 2016-04-07 |
| 3969 | Pat | Ross | 2015-05-21 |

Any help?

Comment: Have you come across table aliases before? They make queries much easier to read.

Comment: Sorry I havent @DaleK

Comment: @DaleK Do you know how to do this with joins?

Comment: I didn't add all the columns I need i the example that's why I needed the joins @DaleK  Can you explain substitute my query

Comment: @DaleK the row number isn't the issue so the  query have multiple unique ids but I just wanted the most recent actiondate

Comment: @DaleK Is i'm not making sense, using my query is there a way to get the most recent out that output like what I would expect that's all I'm asking using my current query

Comment: @DaleK Can you show me a example plz?

Comment: @DaleK Are you talking about the duplicate question?

Comment: @DaleK Thats all you had to say